# VPN + IP Route headaches

Tags: connection, vpn, iptables

I followed a guide [here](http://makezine.com/projects/browse-anonymously-with-a-diy-raspberry-pi-vpntor-router/) to turn my raspberry pi into a vpn router for my PS3. Basically it uses the Wi-Fi connection of the Pi to share internet to the ethernet connection.

It works perfectly on one provider, say `PROV-A` but on another provider, say `PROV-B` I have no internet connection. I have checked that the VPN is online and works. From the raspberry, I can ping, curl and my IP is that of the respective providers, but on the PS3 (or laptop that I'm using for troubleshooting on eth0) , I only have internet connection when using `PROV-A`. `PROV-B` doesn't work at all. Is there anything I'm missing? Maybe something on the routing since I don't think it has to do with iptables as it works on one but not on the other.

Ah yes, I also don't have connection when not connected to any VPN which is good since I don't want non-vpn traffic going through eth0.

Here are some configuration files:

#### PROV-A client.conf for openvpn

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 123.xxx.xxx.xxx 443
remote vpn.provider-a.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-client
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth-nocache
remote-cert-tls server
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
log /var/log/openvpn-client.log
```

#### PROV-B client.conf for openvpn

```
client
dev tun1
remote 129.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
remote vpn.provider-b.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca cacert.pem
cert client.crt
key client.key
auth-user-pass auth.txt
verb 4
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
auth-nocache
remote-cert-tls server
log-append /var/log/openvpn-b-client.log
ping 10
ping-restart 30
```

#### route when not connected to any VPN

```
# route -v -n -e
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0

# route -v -e
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.178.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

#### route when connected to PROV-A

```
# route -v -n -e

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.9.0.69       128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.9.0.1        10.9.0.69       255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.9.0.69       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.9.0.69       128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
123.xxx.xxx.xxx 192.168.178.1   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

# route -v -e

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.9.0.69       128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.9.0.1        10.9.0.69       255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.9.0.69       *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.9.0.69       128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
vpn.provider-a. fritz.box       255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.178.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

#### route when connected to PROV-B

```
# route -v -n -e

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface    MSS   Window irtt
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
128.0.0.0       10.42.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
129.xxx.xxx.xxx 192.168.178.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0     0     0      0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0     0     0      0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0    0     0      0

# route -v -e

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface    MSS   Window irtt
default         10.42.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
128.0.0.0       10.42.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1     0     0      0
vpn.provider-b. fritz.box       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0     0     0      0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0     0     0      0
192.168.178.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0    0     0      0
```

#### my `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.custom.conf`

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=eth0,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.250,24h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.10.1 # our router
dhcp-option=6,77.109.148.136 # our DNS Server
dhcp-authoritative # force clients to grab a new IP
```

#### my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.10.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

#### my `/etc/network/iptables`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2329:305964]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1422:170407]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2329:305964]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1999:222660]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [330:83304]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1422:170407]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1752:253711]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [69:4377]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [49:3489]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [86:5816]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun+ -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1884:213027]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [102:6417]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1332:159707]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan  8 10:12:12 2016
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the vpn configs to both have `dev tun` and change your iptables to use:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
COMMIT
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```